# how get socket port number from an accept call (C UNIX)

Tags: c, sockets, unix, port

i've done a simple client/server program where the server wait for an external connection and return the connection-socket if the port number of the client is in the range of [1025-2048] otherwise return -1. The problem is that when i get the port number by the client adress (which should be stored in the `sockaddr` structure) it says me that the client port number is zero, but in the client program i've set the client portnumber to 1999.

**SERVER**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>


int function(int fd_socket) {

    int fd_socket_acc;
    int len;
    int port;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;

    puts("WAITING FOR CLIENT...");

    fd_socket_acc = accept(fd_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &len);

    puts("CONNECTION DONE.");

    port = ntohs (client_addr.sin_port);
    printf("client port number: %d \n", port);


    if (port >= 1024 && port <= 2048) {

        close (fd_socket_acc);
        return fd_socket_acc;
    }   
    else {
        close(fd_socket_acc);
        return -1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    int fd_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in local_addr;

    fd_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_addr.sin_port = htons(1887);
    local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(fd_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));

    listen(fd_socket, 3);

    function(fd_socket);

    //close(fd_socket);

}
```

**CLIENT**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int fd_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in local_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *hp;

    fd_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_addr.sin_port = htons(1999);
    local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(fd_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(1887);
    //hostname is "ubuntu"
    hp = gethostbyname("ubuntu");
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, &server_addr.sin_addr, 4);

    printf("%d \n", ntohs(local_addr.sin_port));

    connect(fd_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    wait(2);

    close(fd_socket);

}
```

If i get the port number in client with a `printf("%d", ntohs(local_addr.sin_port))` it stamps correctly `1999`, but if i get the port number of client in server with `printf("%d", ntohs(client_addr.sin_port))` it stamps `0`. Why?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you are binding the socket in the client side code? It is not logic in the client and server communication. If the client and server port is same then only the connection is established, and you can validate others.

Comment: It is if you have multiple interface on the client too.

Comment: yes bind in client is useless. I used it only to set the client socket port to a specific number for testing

Comment: For what purpose? You shouldn't attempt to control the client port number in any way. It doesn't accompish anything useful, and just makes the client harder (much) to write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to obtain the client port number in `client_addr` through `accept` you have to tell `accept` how big that buffer is by setting

```
socklen_t len = sizeof(client_addr);
```

You can alternatively retrieve it by calling afterwards

```
len = sizeof(client_addr);
getpeername(fd_socket_acc, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &len);
```

Comment: Yes the problem was the len variable not initialized. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you do not set the variable len to anything, and I suspect that your compiler sets it to 0.
What happens is that you try to accept with an undefined len size.

Adding `len=sizeof( struct sockaddr_in );` before making a call to accept would help to fill the passed client_addr correctly.

Comment: Yes the problem was the len variable not initialized. Thank you very much!